# how to populate values entered in textfield to table

Tags: html, mysql

I am trying to generate bill for the customer.When I add items in the form and click on add button I want it to create table and show the bill. But its not working fine. I tried to use sql query but it is showing only 2 items and sometimes blank. when there are 3 4 items inserted into database. Please any one can clear me where am going wrong.

```
  <tr>
  <td height="517"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Add item Details </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="117">Item Name</td>
      <td width="243"><input name="itemName" type="text" id="itemName">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td><input name="qty" type="text" id="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Price </td>
      <td><input name="price" type="text" id="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vat </td>
      <td><input name="vat" type="text" id="vat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>   
 <p align="center">Bill Record</p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp; </p>
  <table width="70%"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>

    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</div></th>
     <th>Vat</th>
   <th>total</th>

  </tr>
   <% double grandTotal=0;
      try
      {
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from bill where cname='"+session.getAttribute("cname")+"' order by datetime asc");
        while(rs.next())
        {
  %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getString("itemName")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("qty")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("price")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("vat")%></td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("total") %></td>
    <% grandTotal+=Double.parseDouble( rs.getString("total"));%>
  </tr>
      <% 
                 }   %>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>grandTotal</td>
      <td><%= grandTotal %> </td>
    </tr>
    <%  con.close();
    }
     catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
  %>

  </table>
 </tr>
```

And here is the code where I am adding values into database.

```
 <% 
    if(request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
    {
       String itemName="";
        int qty;
        double price,vat,total;
        grandTotal=0;
        boolean exists=false;
         itemName=request.getParameter("itemName");
         qty=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("qty"));
          price=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
         vat=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("vat"));
         total=price+vat;

         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
          Date date = new Date();
   try
        {
              Statement st=con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT into bill values('"+session.getAttribute("cname")+"','" + dateFormat.format(date) + "','"+itemName+"','"+qty+"','"+price+"','"+vat+"','"+total+"','"+grandTotal+"')");
          out.println("<script> alert('Item Added Successfully')</script>");


        }
```

Comment: That's neither JS nor SQL.

Comment: after html tags I have used script language, and sql statement i have used to display values in the table.